# URLSessionWebSocketTask: Fatal error: Only one of message or error should be nil

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, urlsession, urlsessionwebsockettask

I've been getting this error randomly since I recently used `URLSessionWebSocketTask`, which causes my program to crash every time:

```
Fatal error: Only one of message or error should be nil
```

But I can't find a specific way to reproduce it, because I have no idea. It doesn't seem to be caused by network quality or any unsafe code I wrote.

So I'd like to ask, have you guys encountered this error recently? I need to know if it's caused by the SDK.

- Xcode 11.3.1 (11C504)
- macOS 10.15.3 (19D76)
- iOS 13.3.1 (17D50)

p.s. I searched the internet and found only [this related thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/117827), and it didn't help.

Answer (score 4):

After some digging, I've found a possible solution which can be found in this repo called websocket-apple, on GitHub: [link](https://github.com/shareup/websocket-apple/blob/master/Sources/WebSocket/WebSocket.swift)

I also encountered this crash when I had the `URLSession`'s `delegateQueue` set to `.main`. In the solution implemented by the [websocket-apple](https://github.com/shareup/websocket-apple) repo, the wrapper around URLSessionWebSocket task creates a new `OperationQueue` and passes it in as the `delegateQueue` when initializing the `URLSession`.

This code block is where the `delegateQueue` to pass into the `URLSession` is created (copied directly from the linked [repo](https://github.com/shareup/websocket-apple/blob/master/Sources/WebSocket/WebSocket.swift#L55))

```
private let webSocketQueue: DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "WebSocket.webSocketQueue")
private lazy var delegateQueue: OperationQueue = {
    let queue = OperationQueue()
    queue.name = "WebSocket.delegateQueue"
    queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
    queue.underlyingQueue = webSocketQueue
    return queue
}()
```

And [line 77](https://github.com/shareup/websocket-apple/blob/master/Sources/WebSocket/WebSocket.swift#L77) has the initialization of the `URLSession`:

```
let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: delegate, delegateQueue: delegateQueue)
```